# SQL - Order By Field in Random Numeric Order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL query which I need to use to order a field. Typically a query would go something like this in hibernate

select * from model order by model.field1, model.field2
The issue is that the first sort needs to be done in a very specific order.

Where the order in field1 has to be filtered in a SPECIFIC order.

So instead of listing cars by an alphabetical order for example. I would prefer to sort in say
Lexus, Ford, Toyota, Mazda, Mercedes etc. Is there a clean way to do this? Currently I get the result and then have to put it in specific lists and is just not very clean.  I do not have option of modifying things in the database

Thanks.

Comment: BTW, you are not really talking about a random order. More a prescribed order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom ORDER BY using a CASE statement.
The CASE statement checks for your condition and assigns to rows which meet that condition a lower value than that which is assigned to rows which do not meet the condition.
It's probably easiest to understand given an example:

```
  SELECT mycolumn
    FROM model 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN model.field1 = 'Lexus'    THEN 0 
              WHEN model.field1 = 'Ford'     THEN 1
              WHEN model.field1 = 'Toyota'   THEN 2
              WHEN model.field1 = 'Mazda'    THEN 3
              WHEN model.field1 = 'Mercedes' THEN 4 END, model.field2;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
order by (case
 when field1 = 'Lexus' then 1
 when field1 = 'Ford' then 2
 when field1 = 'Toyota' then 3
 ...
 else null end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use window functions and the PARTITION BY clause like so:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY manufacturer ORDER BY field1) [RN],
       manufacturer,
       field1,
       field2

FROM model
```

This will give a row number for each different grouping in the partition by clause based on the ordering of field1 in this example.

EDIT:

If your RDMS does not support window functions, you can order by manufacturer then a second value - this would 'group' all the rows for each manufacturer together:

```
SELECT manufacturer, field1

FROM model

ORDER BY manufacturer, field1
```

Comment: This would work in some other RDBMSs, but I don't believe MySQL supports windowing functions.

Comment: If that's the case, then disregard my answer. I dont work with mySQL but was under the impression that window functions were in the standard vendor generic SQL implementation:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2003